# Shell-script removing subdirectories in a for-loop

Tags: sh

The small script below is intended to loop over the subdirectories of the supplied path, perform some operations on files in those subdirectories, and then delete everything under those subdirectories leaving the subdirectories intact but empty.

```
#!/bin/sh
basedir=$1

for subdir in $(find "$basedir" -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d); do
    dir=`basename $subdir`

    # Some other code here
    # ...

    echo "Removing subdirectories $subdir/*"
    rm -rfv "$dir/*"
done
```

For example the below directory tree:

```
.
├── test1
│   ├── db_1422323507_1421673171_272
│   │   └── rawdata
│   ├── db_1423828548_1423645476_289
│   │   └── rawdata
│   ├── db_1423837057_1423828554_290
│   │   └── rawdata
│   ├── db_1423838029_1423837138_291
│   │   └── rawdata
│   └── db_1424102912_1423838103_292
│       └── rawdata
├── test2
├── test3
│   ├── db_1430478916_1429109291_82
│   │   └── rawdata
│   ├── db_1430517825_1430478932_83
│   │   └── rawdata
│   ├── db_1430518751_1430518207_84
│   │   └── rawdata
│   └── db_1430920306_1430913191_86
│       └── rawdata
├── test4
│   └── db_1436338354_1430920324_100
│       └── rawdata
└── test5
```

After running the script `./myscript.sh .` I would expect to see the following directory tree.

```
.
├── test1
├── test2
├── test3
├── test4
└── test5
```

But the script doesn't appear to delete anything, the *other code* works as expected on the files/folders underneath the subdirectories.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't iterate over the output of `find` with a for loop here, but `find` is not necessary, either. The trailing `/` in the pattern will prevent `subdir` from being set to non-directory filesystem entries. Also, don't quote the `*` in the argument to `rm`.

```
#!/bin/sh
basedir=$1

for subdir in "$basedir"/*/; do
    dir=`basename $subdir`

    # Some other code here
    # ...

    echo "Removing subdirectories $subdir/*"
    rm -rfv "$dir/"*
done
```

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
    rm -rfv "$subdir/*"
```

instead of referencing `$dir`. I expect this will make a difference if `$basedir` is a path with directories in it, e.g. something like `a/b/c`.

Also, try omitting the `-f` option from the `rm` command and it might print out some error messages which will help you debug the problem.